# Deploy taking hours on Github: "waiting for github-pages deployment approval"

Tags: html, github, github-actions, github-pages

I tried to commit a change for a Github pages site. It reads: "deploy is waiting for github-pages deployment approval" and doesn't update the site. I've used Github pages frequently and this has never happened before. Any ideas as to what's causing this or how to fix it? This is in Github actions. I'm using Github in browser.

I tried cancelling and re-doing the change, I tried changing something in a different file, and I tried deleting and re-creating a page, all with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [Incident with Actions, API Requests and Pages](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/ws2l6203cs7g)

> Pages is experiencing degraded performance
>
> We are seeing failures in Actions jobs using environments.
> Downstream impact on the deployments of GitHub Pages.
>
> The fix for failing Actions jobs using environments is rolling out. We are expecting the rollout to take several hours to complete.
> The impact on GitHub Pages continues.

The incident has been closed and your pages should be updated in a timely fashion now.

Answer (score 0):

I did face this type pf problem at that time i make sure that the correct branch is selected for deployment in your repository settings and Verify that the branch you want to deploy is specified as the source for GitHub Pages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).